# Widget constantly reloads on device screen

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, icloud, widgetkit

I am using widget with CoreData and iCloud. They share the same App Group container. Everything works fine for a little, but spontaneously widget starts constantly reload and block itself on the device screen and in Widget Dashboard (place where you can search and add any widget).

It happens on iPhone Simulator (I use iPhone 8) and on a physical device as well. On device it behaves better, e.g., it can reload for a while and then stop.

My thoughts that it is connected to `NSPersistentContainer` but I'm not sure. I've tried these with no luck:

1. lazily load everything that goes with Core Data: CoreDataStack, PersistentContainer, etc.
2. use `container.performBackgroundTask()` to return data in `getTimeline(in:completion:)` faster. I have tested with only 1 record, results are the same.
3. remove everything with Core Data and put example code to show static text - that works, reloads disappear, but I need to show real data

In deferent scenarios I see these log messages:

```
1) -[EXSwiftUI_Subsystem beginUsing:withBundle:] unexpectedly called multiple times
2) Bogus event received by listener connection
3) [lifecycle] WARNING: Did not receive handshake message from the host after waiting ~2 seconds. THIS MAY BE A SPURIOUS LAUNCH OF THE PLUGIN due to a message to an XPC endpoint other than the main service endpoint, or the CPU is highly contended and this extension or its host is not getting enough CPU time.
```

and sometimes crashes with

```
1) signal SIGTERM
2) [NSConcreteFileHandle fileDescriptor]: unknown error
```

I can't figure out why it happens. I confused because it sometimes works and show my Core Data records, and reloads timeline correctly, but sometimes it goes crazy.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Xcode 12.0.1 (12A7300)

Device: iPhone Xs, iOS 14.0.1

Comment: How and when you are reloading the widget?

Comment: I'm using only one widget (I have second one to display some debug info, which isn't go to production), I use `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()` when user update/add/delete record in database. Timeline reloads every day at midnight (`Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(date))`) and updates entries every hour or never if there is only one entry depending on conditions (`Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .never)`).

Comment: You should not reload the widget for every change, you can for example reload the widget in sceneDidEnterBackground.

Comment: These changes occur rarely, e.g. to update user need to open a new screen, modify record and confirm his action. I don't even need to reload widget on sceneDidEnterBackground event, because records stay the same. And usually user would have about 20 records only and wouldn't use my app every day.

Comment: The calendar app reloads its widget with every change, no issues there.